# "indent" adds no blank line after void function body

Tags: c, indentation

GNU `indent` (2.2.12) does not add a blank line after a void function:

```
$ echo 'void B(int *b) { *b += 2; } void C(int *c) { *c += 3; }' | indent -kr

void B(int *b)
{
    *b += 2;
} void C(int *c)
{
    *c += 3;
}
```

If I add a `return` statement at the end of `B()`, the output looks correct. Is that a bug?

Comment: The output you present is certainly surprising.  I don't think it is the intended result, and I especially don't think that it is intended that the whitespace output between consecutive function definitions should depend on the contents of the body of the first function, so long as that body is valid C.  So yes, I would consider the behavior you present to be buggy.

Comment: Don't know if it's a bug, but it is strange. I don't think any of the switches do it, either. Instead of trying every single one to maybe get it to work, how about passing it to `sed 's/\}/\}\n/g' | indent -kr`? You'd think there'd be a "blank after brace option" or something.

Comment: indent was always quite buggy. There was a nice GUI "Universal Indent" that could be used to combine various broken code beautifiers into a single non-broken one. Doesn't look like it's maintained any longer, but still available.